# How do I prevent browsers from using an old cached index.html?

Tags: apache, caching, mod-rewrite, mod-expires

I'm redoing an entire website and the browser is using the cached `index.html` of pages that are at the same URL.

This is the entire content of the `.htaccess` file in one of the problem directories:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /products/

    # Remove 'index.html' from the URL for old links that include it.
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\index\.html?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/products/$1" [R=301,L]

    # Use index.php for all requests.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ /products/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# An atempt to tell the browser not to use a cached .html file.
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"

<FilesMatch "\.(html)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

I've tried multiple things here, but nothing is working. This is all I see in the headers:

```
Request URL:http://www.example.com/products/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
```

There are no Request Headers or Response Headers.

I'm thinking I can maybe try a RewriteRule to add something like `?28032012` to the end of something, but I don't know how to even attempt that.

Comment: Can you not edit the index.html page itself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748193/html-php-page-being-cached-client-side-when-it-should-not-be

Comment: I can, but I need to push the site live as soon as possible.

Comment: It looks like mod_expires don't working at all. Are you sure you have uncomment LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so ? Before that you should clear the temporary file of your browser. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using for this was to redirect all www requests to non www requests. So basically, this approach prevented any browsers from using any cached resources because the www version of the site no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

This is worked for me.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>
```

Reference: https://wp-mix.com/disable-caching-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

I've read that appending ?version=<%=version%> to problematic file names is a good method of cache busting.  You may also try as an easier solution the http header "cache-control: max-age = 600" so that anything on the page that is 10 minutes or older is pulled from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can just append /? to the end of your URL.
Example:

```
www.google.com/?
```